# Reduction of Space between two Sub-figures

Tags: spacing, subfloats

I want to reduce the space between two subfigures and use that space to make those subfigures large. How to do that? My code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[1a]{\label{fig1:a}\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{./fig1a.eps}}\hfill
  \subfigure[1b]{\label{fig1:b}\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{./fig1b.eps}}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Assuming that the `\hfill` is there to place the figures towards either side of the margin, you can just make them bigger. The `\hfill` should auto adjust.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 75):

Consider the following minimal example that shows three different ways of spacing sub-figures:

1. Maximum length
2. Equal lengths
3. Fixed length

[image: Different lengths separating subfigures]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  % Maximum length
  \subcaptionbox{1a\label{fig1:a}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{1b\label{fig1:b}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-a}}%

  \bigskip

  % Equal length
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \subcaptionbox{2a\label{fig2:a}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-b}}\hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{2b\label{fig2:b}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-b}}%
  \hspace*{\fill}%

  \bigskip

  % Fixed length
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{3a\label{fig3:a}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-c}}\hspace{1em}%
  \subcaptionbox{3b\label{fig3:b}}{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}​
```

The [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was loaded to highlight the text block boundaries. Note the use of `%` for precise spacing. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) for more on this.

1. **Maximum length**: Here a stretchable length of `\hfill` is used to push both subfigures to the edges of the text block. Note the `%` at the end of the second subfigure, if you're placing content on the following line.
2. **Equal lengths**: A stretchable length is placed on either side of the subfigures to equalize the length from the text block boundary as well as between the subfigures. Note the use of `\hspace*{\fill}` on either side of the subfigures, while `\hfill` suffices between them.
3. **Fixed length**: Use a fixed `\hspace{<len>}` between the subfigures, together with `\centering` to centre and separate the subfigures by a fixed distance `<len>` (`1em` in my example).

Some comments:

- Note the use of `%` at the end of lines. They do add spurious spaces in your output. While it may not be visible, you may not get exact lengths otherwise. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) for more on this.
- Only method 3 (fixed length) requires `\centering`, unless you're also providing a `figure` caption (which you didn't in your code snippet. Moreover, using `\label` without a `\caption` does not help here. It works within `\subcaptionbox` (from [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)), since it writes a caption, but you would still need a separate `\caption` for your `figure` environment for `\label{fig1}` to yield anything.

Comment: For the equal length case exists a special function called "\hfil" with only one "l". This does exactly the same as your code :)

Answer (score 6):

use a relative width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% only for demo
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% [demo] only for demo
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
  % Maximum length
  \subfloat[1a]{\label{fig1:a}\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{fig1a}}\hfill
  \subfloat[1b]{\label{fig1:b}\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{fig1b}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the `subfig` package introduces a default space of a little less than `1em` between two figures.  I still need them tight, as the two figures correspond in major features, so I found it helpful to tweak the spacing with negative horizontal space as well.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Subfigure caption 1.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth] {img1.png}
        \label{fig:img1} } \hspace*{-0.9em}
    \subfloat[Subfigure caption 2.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth] {img2.png}
        \label{fig:img2} } \\
    \caption{Two corresponding images.}
    \label{fig:img}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This could be due to a spurious space within the `\subfloat` command. See [What is the use of percent signs at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 4):

To use all the space available remove the hfill (or keep it, it doesn't really change) and set a relative width `.49\textwidth`. You may actually want to try a slightly lower value to leave some space between them.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[1a]{\label{fig1:a}\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{./fig1a.eps}}
  \subfigure[1b]{\label{fig1:b}\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{./fig1b.eps}}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be the best solution for me as it allows to keep using the subfigure environment.

Original post : [Syntax similar to \centering for right and left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91566/syntax-similar-to-centering-for-right-and-left)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, right]{img1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, left]{img2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```