# Syntax similar to \centering for right and left?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

For images, we can use `\centering`. Is there anything available to align the image to the right side or the left side of the page.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

For general text you can use `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` to align the material to the left and right, respectively. To align images inside a `figure` easily you can use the `adjustbox` package which allows you to add alignment keys to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,center]{example-image}
    \caption{centered image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,left]{example-image}
    \caption{left aligned image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,right]{example-image}
    \caption{right aligned image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

For new documents, especially if many `adjustbox` keys are used, I recommend to use the `\adjustimage{<keys>}{<filename>}` macro instead of `\includegraphics`. The `export` option is then not required anymore. There is also the possibility to do the whole `figure` using one `\adjustimage` use by using the keys `caption`, `label` and `figure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \adjustimage{width=.6\textwidth,center}{example-image}
    \caption{centered image}
\end{figure}

% or even shorter
\noindent\adjustimage{width=.6\textwidth,center,caption={your caption},label={some label},figure}{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we apply this approach for tikzfigure inside figure?

Comment: @alper: You can use `\begin{adjustbox}{center}\begin{tikzfigure} ... \end{tikzfigure}\end{adjustbox}` to center tikzfigures. `center` also accepts an optional width and you can of course add more arguments. See the `adjustbox` manual.

Answer (score 28):

Consider the following examples:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics{n}
 \caption{\texttt{none}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \hfill\includegraphics{n}
 \caption{\texttt{hfill}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{flushright}% or better \raggedleft see comments below
  \includegraphics{n}
  \caption{\texttt{flushright}}
 \end{flushright}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \hfill\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics{n}
  \caption{\texttt{minipage}}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can choose now. I personally prefer the `minipage` approach.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you should use the `flushright` environment inside a `figure` for the same reason as you shouldn't use `center`. The vertical spacing might be wrong.

Comment: I agree,  particularly because it is not necessary since `hfill` is sufficient. I just wanted to show a few more possibilities. I added a comment...

Answer (score 9):

If it isn't a floating images you can use `\flushright` or `\flushleft`.
Also you may put `\hfil` from the right or left of image block.

Comment: `flushright` and `flushleft` are intended as environments cf `center` the analogues of `\centering` are `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,left]{example-image}
    \caption{left aligned image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```