# Package keyval Error: center undefined

Tags: graphics

When trying to force an image to be centered, I get the following error:

*! Package keyval Error: center undefined.See the keyval package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... {\sffamily\centering }*

This is the code I am using

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
      \includegraphics[width=200pt, center]{./pictures/arcsdeobr.png}
      \caption[ArcSDE logic]{ArcSDE logic(source: ArcSDE)}
      \label{fig:ArcSDE logic}
  \end{figure}
```

My classmate that has been using the same template does not have this issue when using "center".

Answer (score 3):

`center` is not a standard key for `\includegraphics`. Use `\centering`, if you want to center the contents of the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=200pt]{./pictures/arcsdeobr.png}
  \caption[ArcSDE logic]{ArcSDE logic(source: ArcSDE)}
  \label{fig:ArcSDE logic}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91580) explains:

> To align images inside a figure easily you can use the adjustbox package which allows you to add alignment keys to `\includegraphics`

So adding the following code somewhere before that code should do the trick:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```