# Aligning the figures

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, alignment

I have 10 figures. How can I find the best (the most beautiful) configuration? I want to arrange them as below:
a single panel at the left, and nine panels (3*3) below it (like an "L"). How can I align the first (single) panel at the left?

I attach the configuration that I have made already. Sorry for attaching a screenshot, the relations are too complicated to bring here.

```
\begin{figure*}
%\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{01}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{02}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{03}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{04}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{05}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{06}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{07}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{08}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{09}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{10}
\caption{The modified Toomre's criterion, density plot interms of $\xi$ and 
dimensionless raduis $y$ for models summarized in Table \ref{table1}. Each 
panel has been titled with the corresponding model. The white era in all 
models indicates the stability zone.\label{dp}}
\end{figure*}
```

I have used this template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monthly-notices-of-the-royal-astronomical-society-mnras-latex-template-and-guide-for-authors/kqnjzrwjwjth#.Wwr6MjSFPIX

[image]

Comment: What did you do to center the first one? If you have `\centering` or similar, just remove that.

Comment: There is no need to post the whole code, but posting the list of your packages and how did you put the figures (minipages, subfigures, centering, etc.) whould be helpful.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. : I removed \centering  but it is still at center :/

Comment: @Ak68 you should post your code, at list the part that I've told you. You could also use a 'frog' as picture, we're interested in the code of the document, not of the pictures.

Comment: However, imho, it would be better to show the first image bigger, like 3 times what is now, if they fit in a page.

Comment: @gvgramazio : "frog" :)) so funny. I just bring the part of the code and also the template I am using

Comment: In your template all figures are centered. Try to set a left alignment before the first figure and then a center alignment after the first figure.

Comment: @gvgramazio: Would you please mention the command?

Comment: However, I suggest you to use the `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` package. It doesn't solve your problem, it's just a better way to insert figures.

Comment: The analogues of `\centering` command are `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`. The analogues of `center` environment are `flushleft` and `flushright` environments.

Comment: The two options that you could try are `[...]{\raggedleft \includegraphics{01}}[...]` or `[...]\includegraphics{01}\hfill[...]`

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering) the difference between `\centering` command and `center` environment and why you shouldn't use the latter for figures. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91566/syntax-similar-to-centering-for-right-and-left) a more detailed explanation on how you could align figures. Note that in your case _do nothing_ is the same of using `\centering`.

Comment: However, try and let me know if the solution works for you. If not, the reason is the redefinition of `figure` in the class you're using and _we_ (that means _you_ :D ) need to reredefine it.

Comment: @gvgramazio: Actually `\raggedright` works out. Thank you

Comment: Glad to being helpful.