# How to rightalign the picture in the framebox?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

In the following code, the logo is centered in the framebox.
How can I get it aligned to the right?

`keepaspectratio, right` does not work...contrary to what I found on the net.

Error: "Package xkeyval Error: 'right' undefined in families 'Gin'. \newpage"

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=4.6cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand\BackgroundStructure{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \setlength\fboxsep{0mm}
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.5mm}
    \put(10, 10){\fcolorbox{red}{red!10}{\framebox(155,247){}}} % mainr
    \put(165, 10){\fcolorbox{blue}{blue!10}{\framebox(37,247){}}} % margin
    \put(10, 262){\fcolorbox{green}{green!10}{\framebox(192, 25){{\includegraphics[height=23mm,keepaspectratio]{C:/ProgramData/.../.../logo.jpg}}}}} % header
}

\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l r | l r}
        \textbf{Project} & new project & \textbf{Pag.} & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage} \\
        \textbf{Nr.} & 2020-000A & \textbf{Date} & $\today$ \\
        \textbf{Program version} & 1.5 &  & \\
        \textbf{Calculated by} & John & \textbf{Company} & \textbf{Doe Chemical}\\
\end{tabular}}

%\graphicspath{ logo folder }
\begin{document}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundStructure}
    \section{Results}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{Limit:}\\
        vertical:  & 2.7 $ \leq$ 18.8 & OK\\
        Horizontal: & 52.5 $\leq$ 398 & OK\\
        for class: & 1 & OK\\
        for class: & 1 & OK\\
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{State:}\\
        Geometric stability: &  & OK\\
    \end{tabular}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Place `\hfill` directly before the `\includegraphics` command and the image should be right aligned inside of the green box.

Comment: What does "keepaspectratio, right does not work...contrary to what I found on the net."  refer to? From the quoted error message, I guess, you tried adding `right` to the optional argument of `\includegraphics`. Where exactly did you  find this information?

Comment: I guess, you found the `right` option for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91580/134144. Please be aware, that the `adjustbox` package in this question is loaded with the `export` option, an option you did not include. You need this option in order to be able to use key originally defined for `\adjustbox` with `\includegraphics` as well. Thus, using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` should help getting rid of the error message.

Comment: @leandriis: I didn't. I tried everything. I still have difficulty in finding the right doc sources. A lot is outdated, new packages seem to appear daily, etc.

Comment: @leandriis: And second: it seems to work with \hfill AND  without export/adjustbox...

Comment: The only thing needed to get the alignment you want to achieve is indeed the `\hfill` command. My remarks about `adjustbox` were ment to explain why you got the error message in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `\hfill` at the relevant place:

```
 \put(10, 262){\fcolorbox{green}{green!10}{\framebox(192, 25){{\hfill%
  \includegraphics[height=23mm,keepaspectratio]{pepe-le-pew1.jpg}}}}}
```

(I don't have your logo,and I had to replace it with one of mine)
[image]