# How to insert text next to figure and align two figures placed on top of each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats

How do I add a text beside a figure and still have the figure align? I tried using the `\includegraphics[left]` and `\includegraphics[right]` commands but you can see the figures and text are still not aligned.

I am following the solution here [Syntax similar to \centering for right and left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91566/syntax-similar-to-centering-for-right-and-left)

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {Left Hand \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip,left]{figures/qualitative/segmentation-l.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {Right Hand \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip,left]{figures/qualitative/segmentation-r.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: it is hard to guess what you want `left` to do, you can not just make up key names and expect they do something. `\includegraphics` is positioned in _exactly_ the way a letter is positioned,  `Left hand X` has X to the right of the text  `X Left hand` has X to the left, same is true if you replace `X` by `\includegraphics` except you have `width=0.9\textwidth` so there is hardly any space for text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i am following the solution posted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91566/syntax-similar-to-centering-for-right-and-left I just want the right end of the bar chart to be aligned and the text to be right aligned too

Comment: well how can anyone know you have used a non standard package adding extra keys to a standard command unless you tell us?? you have been on the site long enough to know all examples should be complete so they show the problem nd do not rquire people to guess definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alternative.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
        
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}     
        Left Hand  &\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}\\
        Right Hand &\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}\\
    \end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

Or using the package `subcaption` (or `subfig`) using two nodes, one for the "hands" and another for the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    Hands/.style={
    below left = 0.2ex and 3.0ex,
    anchor= east,
    inner sep=0,
    text width=15ex,  
    align = right, 
     },
}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0] (image) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
            \node[Hands] (label) at (image.west) {\strut Left Hand};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0] (image) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}};
            \node[Hands] (label) at (image.west) {\strut Right Hand};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```