# Two figures with two sub-figures each on same page

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need a layout like this on a single page without any other text or floats.

```
| figure 1a | figure 1b |

   Caption for Figure 1


| figure 2a | figure 2b |

   Caption for Figure 2
```

Do anyone know what to do with it?

Comment: Do you need a caption for each of the subfigures as well? That is, do you want them numbered 1a, 1b, 2a and 2b or just a combined Figure 1 and Figure 2 caption?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not interested in separate sub-captions for each of the sub-figures, then you can get away with only the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,afterpage}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\afterpage{\clearpage}% To make sure the image appears on the following page
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \null\hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  \hfill\null%
  \caption{This is the first figure}

  \null\hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  \hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \hfill\null%
  \caption{This is the second figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

`\hfill`s stretches out the space beside each sub-float, similar to what is achieved in [Reduction of space between two sub-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42975/5764) (with `\hspace*{\fill}`).

---

If you want sub-captions as well, then you need to include a package that provides that functionality. Here's one such implementation using the [`subcaption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

[image]

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
%...
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \null\hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{sub 1a}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{sub 1b}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \hfill\null%
  \caption{This is the first figure}

  \null\hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{sub 2a}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{sub 2b}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \hfill\null%
  \caption{This is the second figure}
\end{figure}
```

Other options (with a slightly different interface) would be to use [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) (not the *obsolete* [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)).