# Two videos side by side in one slide beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, multimedia

How can I add two videos in one slide side by side. Both videos should be in a horizontal line. The following code put a video above the other video.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{ Results}


\includemedia[
  label      = AA,
  width      = 110mm,
  height     = 50mm,
  activate   = pageopen,
  addresource= master.mov,
  flashvars={flv=master.mov & autoplay=0}
]{}{player_flv_maxi.swf}

\includemedia[
  label      = BB,
  width      = 110mm,
  height     = 50mm,
  activate   = pageopen,
  addresource= master.mov,
  flashvars={flv=master.mov & autoplay=0}
]{}{player_flv_maxi.swf}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Do not leave an empty line between the two constructions.

Comment: @Werner, wow. thanks alot. Another two questions, how can I add title for each vidoe? and how can I play them by pressing one button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set each `.swf` in a `minipage` to block them in; this allows you to set a heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{ Results}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  \centering Heading A

  \includemedia[
    label      = AA,
    width      = \linewidth,
    height     = 50mm,
    activate   = pageopen
  ]{}{file.swf}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  \centering Heading B

  \includemedia[
    label      = BB,
    width      = \linewidth,
    height     = 50mm,
    activate   = pageopen
  ]{}{file.swf}
\end{minipage}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Placement of the elements can be adjusted using information from [Reduction of Space between two Sub-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42968/5764).

You don't need the `\fbox`, of course.