# how can I put multiple video next to each other on one slide presentation

Tags: beamer, animations

I can easily play one movie using the following

```
\documentclass[11pt] {beamer}
\usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[poster,autoplay,text={\small play dead}]{6cm}{6cm}{dead.mp4}
\includemovie[poster,autoplay,text={\small run as fast as you can}]{6cm}{6cm}{run.mp4}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to know how I can play two side by side.

I tried to use another solution but I get error, [Two videos side by side in one slide beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179872/two-videos-side-by-side-in-one-slide-beamer)

```
\documentclass[11pt] {beamer}
    \usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{ Results}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering Heading A
    \includemedia[label = AA, width = \linewidth, height = 50mm, activate = pageopen]{}{run.mp4}
    \end{minipage}}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering Heading B
    \includemedia[ label = BB, width = \linewidth, height = 50mm,  activate = pageopen]{}{run.mp4}
    \end{minipage}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the error like : Undefined control sequence. ...\centering Heading A\ includemedia [label =AA, width= \line...

Comment: I think for using `\includemedia` you need `\usepackage{media9}` not `\usepackage{movie15}`

Comment: The first example works fine for me, although you should notice that the `movie15` package is obsolete

Comment: @samcarter you are amazing, after I added the "\usepackage{media9}" it seems to work, but I have no power on putting them in a distance next to each other. or play with their position. Would you please help me with that ?

Comment: To add space between the videos, you could add `\hspace{1cm}` or `\hfill` between the minipages

Comment: @samcarter is there a possibly to add 6 videos in one slide and each time you click on one, it fade the others but make the vedio bigger ?

Comment: Will the sequence of videos be predetermined?

Comment: @samcarter yes for example, I have 6 videos , they are called 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6 and I want to each time click on one

Comment: I guess you could make a frame that includes images of your videos and then have extra frames which show the video in big, e.g. https://pastebin.com/8gTFnn4T

Comment: If you need another order than 1,2,3... you could make the images hyperlinks that would jump to the frame with the big video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two videos side-by-side, using `media9`. The right one configured to auto-play when the page opens and to loop (replay infinitely):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Two videos}
\includemedia[
  addresource=example-movie.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=3.2cm,height=1.8cm,
  flashvars={
     source=example-movie.mp4
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\includemedia[
  addresource=example-movie.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=3.2cm,height=1.8cm,
  flashvars={
      source=example-movie.mp4
     &autoPlay=true
     &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```