# Reduce space between 2 figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm trying to display 2 figures sides by sides but I would like to reduce the space between them, how can I do ?

My code so far:

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \advance\leftskip-2cm
    \subfloat[Recheche de noeuds]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.26]{getNodeRange.png} }}%
     \qquad 
    \subfloat[Recheche d'arcs]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.26]{getEdgeRange.png} }}%

    \caption{Recherche sur base d'une propriété dans un intervalle}%    
    \label{fig:example}%
 \end{figure}
```

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Pleasse add the word `demo` in the brakets when loading `documentclass`. How much space is left? Additionally, there is a `\qquad` between the figures.

Comment: As Johannes says, you have explicitly *added* space with `\qquad`, so removing that is good first step. If it's not enough, look at your actual images, and see if there is any whitespace in those.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Reduction of Space between two Sub-figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42975/579)

Answer (score 1):

Removing  \qquad  solved the problem